# Create Function with IF_THEN_ELSE statement with Copypaste action

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

```
Function UC (x As String)

If x = "Not Yet Start" or _

x = "In-Progress" Then

UC = "N/a"

If x = "Complete" Then

UC= Format (Now, "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss")

Else

Cells(x).Copy

ActiveSheet.Cells(x).PasteSpecial

End If

End Function
```

[image]

i want to create a function where when i put Current Status as Not yet Start/In-Progress so column "DateComplete" will appear as N/a then when i put Complete then Date will appear in column "Date Complete". Later when i want to change Current Status to Shipped. i don't want the Date Complete will empty due to function IF_*THEN_*ELSE operate where when the statement is false, so it changes the action. so, i thought if i copy the date in Date Complete then paste special (onlyvalue) to the same column (Date Complete) then the date will not be changed then the function will be removed so it will not affect the date.

so, the problem right now, The Vba coding have many errors, can anyone help? or any better suggestion for me. If i use Excel formula =today() then the date will change tomorrow. that why i want to use VBA coding.

Solve my error and ensure the function can be use

Answer (score 0):

This is not a user function, rather check that a change was made in column D.

Place this code in the sheet's code module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  If Not IsDate(Target.Offset(0, 2)) Then  'modification

    If Target = "Not Yet Start" Or Target = "In-Progress" Then
      Target.Offset(0, 2) = "N/A"
    ElseIf Target = "Complete" Then
      Target.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss"
      Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now
    Else
      Target.Offset(0, 2) = "Unknown Status!"
    End If

  End If                'modification

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You may forget `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Comment: @taller In our case it is true, that this sub is invoked when the new value is set in column `F` but makes no harm. For optimize you are right.

Comment: @Blackcat sir, right now if i want the Date Remain unchanged even after i change the current status. is that possible? cause i want record date fix, cant be changed even after i changed to status

Comment: @syaz Added two lines for modificaiton.

Answer (score 0):

- Using `Worksheet_Change` to update `Date Complete` when users change `Current Status`
- Save the code in sheet module (Right click sheet tab > View Code > Paste code )

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const NYS = "Not Yet Start"
    Const INPR = "In-Progress"
    Const COMP = "Complete"
    Const SHIP = "Shipped"
    Const NA = "N/A"
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Column = 4 And .Row > 1 Then
            If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                If StrComp(.Value, NYS, vbTextCompare) = 0 Or StrComp(.Value, INPR, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = NA
                ElseIf StrComp(.Value, COMP, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()
                    .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss"
                ElseIf StrComp(.Value, SHIP, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    ' update for Shipped if needed
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Finally, i get what i want. but how can your coding dont change the date complete even i change the status to shipped @ any other word? can you explain?

Comment: The `ElseIf StrComp(.Value, SHIP, vbTextCompare) = 0` condition matches the users input (Shipped), and you can add code to perform an action (e.g., update `Date Ship` with `Date Complete`). However, as there is currently no code in this section now, the `Date Complete` remains fixed. Omitting this line will yield the same result. btw, I prefer using `StrComp` for text comparison as it is case-insensitive, matching both `Complete` and `complete`.